# POCO Class in EF not working as Expected

Tags: visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5, poco, edmx

I have created a DataBase in SQL and created an EDMX in Visual Studio 2012. It automatically created POCO (TT) classes. Everything looks fine.

Now I change the column name of a table. I update the EDMX. Opening the EDMX in XML and everything looks fine.

## **Question 1**

After I ran Custom tool in TT, I see that a new property got created additionally, e.g.:

```
SQL table name : Student

Column name : sName
```

In my POCO Class

```
public int sName{ get; set; }
```

got automatically created.

Now I change the column name in SQL to

```
Column name : studentName
```

My POCO class

```
public int sName{ get; set; }

public int studentName{ get; set; }
```

Is this a bug or do I need to do something to fix this?

What should I do to avoid this?

## **Question 2**

Also, if I change the data type of any SQL column and update the model from the DB in my EDMX designer, the Conceptual Model is not updated. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 40):

First, to understand your problem, what you need to know is that the [EDMX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj650889) file is just an XML file that contains 3 different sections:

- CSDL: Conceptual schema definition language
- SSDL: Store schema definition language
- MSL: Mapping specification language

The CSDL contains the entities and relationships that make up your conceptual model. The SSDL describes your DB model and the MSL is the mapping between the 2.

The “Update Model From DB” process will update the SSDL (change everything that is inconsistent with the current DB schema), it will only modify the CSDL in case you’ve added new things to your DB schema.

This is quite a normal behavior since your Conceptual schema may/should differ from your DB schema (unless you want your Domain model to look exactly like a DB model which obviously do not sound as OOP/DDD best practices).

As for @Peru, the solution would be to delete the concerned entity (not the entire EDMX!) and then perform the “Update Model From DB” process.

Hope this helps!

**Edit:**

There's a tool, not for free, which is a Visual Studio plugin that allows you apply changes made into the DB, both on the CSDL and SSDL files: [Huagati DBML/EDMX Tools](http://www.huagati.com/dbmltools/).
The only "free" solution is deleting the entity (or the right field within this entity) that needs to be updated.

Remember that CSDL is supposed to be maintained by developers and must look like an Object Model rather than a DB Model. Imagine you have setup inheritance between your entities or that you have split 1 DB table to 2 EDMX entities, running "Update model from DB" should not overwrite everything!

Comment: Deleting the Entity is the only solution ?

Comment: There's an existing VS plugin that does the job. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @MaxS-Betclic: will you give us an example when you say `csdl must look lie an object model rather than a DB model`

Comment: Well, your DB model should differ from your business model. A DB engine will have to deal with other concerns that will lead you to organize the way your data will stored differently than the way you design your Domain. Domain model is all about business where DB model is about storage.

Comment: @AbuHamzah Have a look at [this UncleBob article](http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2013/10/01/Dance-You-Imps.html) and this [EF training](https://techblog.betclicgroup.com/2013/10/08/entity-framework-training/) the go further

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I'd open the edmx file as XML and find the problem node and delete it.  The file is pretty easy to understand - don't be scared to at least try it out.

Answer (score 4):

I know I'm a bit late here but there *is* a relatively simple way to generate your POCOs/update your DbContext from the EDMX designer.

Go to your designer, right click on the empty area, click "Update Model from Database", add/update your tables. This will update your edmx XML. After you've verified that your table has been added to the CSDL, SSDL, and MSL sections, right click on your T4 template in the solution explorer (`<Name>.tt`, not `<Name>.Context.tt`) and click "Run Custom Tool" - this will generate POCOs for any updated objects. Note that if you are creating new entities, they will not be added to your DbContext class, you will still have to do this manually by adding the following line at the bottom of your class: `public virtual DbSet<Entity_Name_Goes_Here> EntityNames { get; set; }`

Comment: My edmx was being updated by using the "Update Model from Database", however the entity class files weren't being created/updated. Running the custom tool on the .tt file created the entity class files that I was missing, thanks :).

Answer (score 1):

Only the manual edit worked for a View in my project.  (going from smallint to decimal(18,2) )

Open the .EDMX file in a text editor, find appropite  section, and manually change the Property Type="..." value.

Answer (score -1):

Once you update the fields in Db, Find the respective model.cs file then delete those fields from the model. now Update the EDMX file (Update Model from Database). It worked for me.