# Entity Designer / Entity Framework / edmx - update only storage model (not conceptual model)

Tags: .net, entity-framework, edmx, edmx-designer, entity-model

I have created a conceptual model and I've mapped it to storage model.
Then I've been making changes to DB, adding/changing/etc fields.

What I want now is to update the mappings between my new DB structure and a conceptual model, but I do NOT want the Update Model Wizard to change my conceptual model (not even adding fields to it - it results in a big mess).

My problem is that when I go to Mapping Window, under tables (left column) it still shown the fields from the storage model, which is now out of sync with my updated DB.

It seems I need to update the storage model, so I can select the correct fields in Mapping Window.  But how is this possible?   Or is there other way around this?

Answer (score 1):

The EDMX file is an XML file that is a combination of 3 different parts that make up the whole thing. If you right-click on your EDMX file and choose "Open with... XML Editor" you'll see the 3 different sections:

- `<edmx:ConceptualModels>`
- `<edmx:StorageModels>`
- `<edmx:Mappings>`

These sections can be edited manually, at your own risk!  :-)

Have a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15545469/poco-class-in-ef-not-working-as-expected/16216388#16216388) where I give a little more details on CSDL, SSDL, MSL and how things are updated. I also give a link to this tool that might help you out as well.

Note that it's also possible to generate CSDL, SSDL & MSL files rather than having them embedded in the binary file, by changing the "Meta Artifact Processing" property of your model to "Copy to Output Directory".