# Missing DbModel.Context.cs file under DbModel.Context.tt

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, visual-studio, entity-framework

I'm new to ASP.NET and just managed to configure my machine to be able to Update my EFModel from a distant MySql database.

I had to install MySql Connector 6.9.8 and MySql for Visual Studio 1.2.7. Everything was working well and I was able to build my API without problems. So after installing MySql Connector 6.9.8 I followed [these steps](http://qursaan-howto.blogspot.de/2014/07/solve-your-project-references-latest.html) to get rid of the EntityFramework error.

Just after that I updated my model from my database and wanted to publish my project to check whether the newly created fields of my table were well linked, I got an error:

> “The type or namespace 'UphairDbEntities' could not be found”

Since I didn't touch a thing in my API or WebApp project before, I checked on a backup of this project and I figured out I was missing the DbModel.context.cs in my EFModel under the file DbModel.Context.tt in my actual version. Why is it missing and how can I generate this file please ?

For the record, I'm using Entity Framework 6.2.0 and MySql.Data/MySql.Data.Entity NuGet packages 6.9.9.

Thanks in advance for you support :)

Comment: Did you try the command "Run Custom Tool" (right-click the tt file in the solution explorer). And does the model validate OK?

Comment: My Validation of model is ok, and when I try to click "Run Custom Tool" in the tt file in explorer it says to me "Fail of the personalized tool 'TextTemplatingFileGenerator'."

Comment: Maybe you should mention the full exception message in your question.

Comment: I mentioned the full Exception message...

Comment: alias “The type or namespace 'UphairDbEntities' could not be found”

Answer (score 1):

Like stated [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e10faf39-510e-4a05-b727-218a642b1e9d/missing-dbmodelcontextcs-file-under-dbmodelcontexttt?forum=adodotnetentityframework), I just had to delete all the files under the edmx (DbModel.Context.tt, DbModel.Designer.cs and DbModel.tt) and to update model from database with Entity Data Model Designer.

Now I understand how Entity works.

Comment: Also found this to be a good resource: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947511/entity-framework-how-do-you-refresh-the-model-when-the-db-changes