# I want to Add multiple Roles at the time of registeration with many to many relationship using EF Models in MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, many-to-many, ef-model-first, ef-model-builder

I have user registration table with roles, i want to register new user with multiple roles via Many-to-Many Ef Models Generated Models.

I have issue while registering users, New Roles are inserted into roles table and than these newly added roles inserted into user_has_roles (Junction) table.

Here is Registration Form Image

[image]

Here is Database Many to Many Relational Tables Image

[image]

Here is EF Model Table Image

[image]

I m sharing some Code that i have write

Auto Generated Model Classes
user.cs

```
public partial class user
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public user()
    {
        this.user_role = new HashSet<user_role>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int user_id { get; set; }
    public string user_email { get; set; }
    public string user_full_name { get; set; }
    public string user_password { get; set; }
    public string user_phone { get; set; }
    public string user_mobile { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> country_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> city_id { get; set; }

    public virtual city city { get; set; }
    public virtual country country { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<user_role> user_role { get; set; }
}
```

user_role.cs

```
public partial class user_role
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public user_role()
    {
        this.users = new HashSet<user>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int user_role_id { get; set; }
    public string user_role_name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> user_role_status { get; set; }
    public string user_role_description { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<user> users { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my db context class (Auto generated

AccountDb.cs

```
public partial class SaholatEntities : DbContext
{
    public SaholatEntities()
        : base("name=SaholatEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<city> cities { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<country> countries { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<sysdiagram> sysdiagrams { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<user> users { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<user_role> user_role { get; set; }

    public virtual int sp_alterdiagram(string diagramname, Nullable<int> owner_id, Nullable<int> version, byte[] definition)
    {
        var diagramnameParameter = diagramname != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("diagramname", diagramname) :
            new ObjectParameter("diagramname", typeof(string));

        var owner_idParameter = owner_id.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("owner_id", owner_id) :
            new ObjectParameter("owner_id", typeof(int));

        var versionParameter = version.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("version", version) :
            new ObjectParameter("version", typeof(int));

        var definitionParameter = definition != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("definition", definition) :
            new ObjectParameter("definition", typeof(byte[]));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("sp_alterdiagram", diagramnameParameter, owner_idParameter, versionParameter, definitionParameter);
    }

    public virtual int sp_creatediagram(string diagramname, Nullable<int> owner_id, Nullable<int> version, byte[] definition)
    {
        var diagramnameParameter = diagramname != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("diagramname", diagramname) :
            new ObjectParameter("diagramname", typeof(string));

        var owner_idParameter = owner_id.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("owner_id", owner_id) :
            new ObjectParameter("owner_id", typeof(int));

        var versionParameter = version.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("version", version) :
            new ObjectParameter("version", typeof(int));

        var definitionParameter = definition != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("definition", definition) :
            new ObjectParameter("definition", typeof(byte[]));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("sp_creatediagram", diagramnameParameter, owner_idParameter, versionParameter, definitionParameter);
    }

    public virtual int sp_dropdiagram(string diagramname, Nullable<int> owner_id)
    {
        var diagramnameParameter = diagramname != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("diagramname", diagramname) :
            new ObjectParameter("diagramname", typeof(string));

        var owner_idParameter = owner_id.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("owner_id", owner_id) :
            new ObjectParameter("owner_id", typeof(int));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("sp_dropdiagram", diagramnameParameter, owner_idParameter);
    }

    public virtual ObjectResult<sp_helpdiagramdefinition_Result> sp_helpdiagramdefinition(string diagramname, Nullable<int> owner_id)
    {
        var diagramnameParameter = diagramname != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("diagramname", diagramname) :
            new ObjectParameter("diagramname", typeof(string));

        var owner_idParameter = owner_id.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("owner_id", owner_id) :
            new ObjectParameter("owner_id", typeof(int));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<sp_helpdiagramdefinition_Result>("sp_helpdiagramdefinition", diagramnameParameter, owner_idParameter);
    }

    public virtual ObjectResult<sp_helpdiagrams_Result> sp_helpdiagrams(string diagramname, Nullable<int> owner_id)
    {
        var diagramnameParameter = diagramname != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("diagramname", diagramname) :
            new ObjectParameter("diagramname", typeof(string));

        var owner_idParameter = owner_id.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("owner_id", owner_id) :
            new ObjectParameter("owner_id", typeof(int));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<sp_helpdiagrams_Result>("sp_helpdiagrams", diagramnameParameter, owner_idParameter);
    }

    public virtual int sp_renamediagram(string diagramname, Nullable<int> owner_id, string new_diagramname)
    {
        var diagramnameParameter = diagramname != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("diagramname", diagramname) :
            new ObjectParameter("diagramname", typeof(string));

        var owner_idParameter = owner_id.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("owner_id", owner_id) :
            new ObjectParameter("owner_id", typeof(int));

        var new_diagramnameParameter = new_diagramname != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("new_diagramname", new_diagramname) :
            new ObjectParameter("new_diagramname", typeof(string));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("sp_renamediagram", diagramnameParameter, owner_idParameter, new_diagramnameParameter);
    }

    public virtual int sp_upgraddiagrams()
    {
        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("sp_upgraddiagrams");
    }
}
```

Here is my Controller Method to register User (POST)

```
    //post register
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(AccountVM obj)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // insert Data into user variable array from obj viewmodel
            var user = new user()
            {
                user_email = obj.user_email,
                user_full_name = obj.user_full_name,
                user_password = obj.user_password,
                user_phone = obj.user_phone,
                user_mobile = obj.user_mobile,
                country_id = obj.country_id,
                city_id = obj.city_id
            };
            var user_roles = new user_role();

            AccountDb.users.Add(user);

            // insert Data into user_has_role variable array from obj viewmodel
            foreach(var item in obj.selectedRoleList)
            {
                user_roles.user_role_id = Convert.ToInt32(item);

                user_roles.users.Add(new user() { user_id = obj.user_id });

                user.user_role.Add(new user_role() { user_role_id = Convert.ToInt32(item) });

            }


            if (AccountDb.SaveChanges() > 0)
            {
                TempData["errorMsg"] = "save";
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["errorMsg"] = "queryError";
                ViewBag.country_id = new SelectList(AccountDb.countries, "country_id", "country_name");
                AccountVM objRole = new AccountVM();
                objRole.getRoleList = AccountDb.user_role.ToList();
                return View(objRole);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["errorMsg"] = "modelError";
            ViewBag.country_id = new SelectList(AccountDb.countries, "country_id", "country_name");
            AccountVM objRole = new AccountVM();
            objRole.getRoleList = AccountDb.user_role.ToList();
            return View(objRole);
        }
    }
```

I want to Register User with multiple roles and roles are already define in roles table select by multi-select, please help me out

when i registered the user with 1 role, new role added to role table and than newly added role assigned to user (Only role_id added to role table), and if i assign 2 roles than 2 will be added to roles table

**EDITED**
[Image of Junction table after registration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQLeh.png)

[Image of user_role table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEqit.png)

Comment: Lot of time waste here for solution 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by doing this

```
//post register
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Register(AccountVM obj)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // insert Data into user variable array from obj viewmodel
        var user = new user()
        {
            user_email = obj.user_email,
            user_full_name = obj.user_full_name,
            user_password = obj.user_password,
            user_phone = obj.user_phone,
            user_mobile = obj.user_mobile,
            country_id = obj.country_id,
            city_id = obj.city_id
        };
        AccountDb.users.Add(user);

        // insert Data into user_has_role variable array from obj viewmodel
        foreach(var item in obj.selectedRoleList)
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(item);
            user_role _user_role = AccountDb.user_role.FirstOrDefault(r => r.user_role_id == id);

            _user_role.users.Add(user);
            user.user_role.Add(_user_role);
        }

        if (AccountDb.SaveChanges() > 0)
        {
            TempData["errorMsg"] = "save";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["errorMsg"] = "queryError";
            ViewBag.country_id = new SelectList(AccountDb.countries, "country_id", "country_name");
            AccountVM objRole = new AccountVM();
            objRole.getRoleList = AccountDb.user_role.ToList();
            return View(objRole);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        TempData["errorMsg"] = "modelError";
        ViewBag.country_id = new SelectList(AccountDb.countries, "country_id", "country_name");
        AccountVM objRole = new AccountVM();
        objRole.getRoleList = AccountDb.user_role.ToList();
        return View(objRole);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You don't save the role in user_role table rather save it in user_has_role table.

```
var user = new user()
    {
        user_email = obj.user_email,
        user_full_name = obj.user_full_name,
        user_password = obj.user_password,
        user_phone = obj.user_phone,
        user_mobile = obj.user_mobile,
        country_id = obj.country_id,
        city_id = obj.city_id
    };
AccountDb.users.Add(user);
AccountDb.SaveChanges(); // save the user so that you can get the user_id 

// insert Data into user_has_role variable array from obj viewmodel
foreach(var item in obj.selectedRoleList)
{
    var user_role = new user_has_role
    {
        user_role_id = Convert.ToInt32(item),
        user_id = user.user_id
    };
    AccountDb.user_has_role.Add(user_role);
}
AccountDb.SaveChanges(); //save changes after all roles are assigned
```

Comment: Ok bro I’ll try this than tell u after a few ours

Comment: i have done like this but not working
AccountDb.users.Add(user);

                var user_roles = new user_role();
@Robbin

Comment: there is no user_has_role class @robbin

Comment: not possible bro i have no user_has_role table in EF-diagram @Robbin

Comment: if you have the table in database, you can update your EF diagram. Refer to this link to update your edmx diagram
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947511/entity-framework-how-do-you-refresh-the-model-when-the-db-changes

Comment: but bro EF diagram not show junction table and not generate junction table class @robbin

Comment: That's not true. EF can detect every table in the database.

Comment: solve my issue look that i post the correct ans.... btw thank you soo much for helping :)