# Invaild column name

Tags: vb.net

So maybe someone can tell me what I am doing wrong here. I try to retrieve one row from a table that has only two columns in it, ID and HighestIDNumber. Each time I run the code, I get the "**Invaild Column Name**" error. I can not figure out why.

```
Public Shared Function NextEID() As String
    Using context As New iTracContext()
        Dim highestEid As highestEmployeeNumber
        highestEid = context.HighestEmpNumber.FirstOrDefault(Function(e) e.hightestIDnumber > 0)
    End Using
End Function
```

I have verified the column names are exactly the same everywhere it is used.

Comment: `HighestIDNumber` is not the same as `hightestIDnumber`.

Comment: Right but how would that produce a run-time error?

Comment: Understood, but I am only using hightestIDnumber. Which is what has me puzzled

Comment: @wakgtech So you're saying you have that typo in the table definition too?

Comment: Your table name is HighestEmpNumber and your column name is hightestIDnumber (with a t). May be correct but unusual. Are you sure that's correct? However that's more likely to through a compiler error than runt time.  So is it possible your EF model has not been updated and so doesn't match the SQL table and could be generating an SQL call with a column name the DB doesn't recognise?

Comment: @wakgtech Is [`Option Strict On`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29985039/1115360)?

Comment: what about [Option Explicit Off](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-explicit-statement)? (not sure it works with object properties or just variables)

Comment: @djv None of those enable you to provide a non existing property name in a strongly typed lambda. For it to happen, `e` has to be `Object` in addition to `option strict off`.

Comment: I think @JonRoberts is spot on and OP should update the model. [LINQ to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1110258/832052), [EF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2959035/832052)

Comment: Sorry for getting back so late to everyone. Andrew Morton, you are correct sir. That typo was the problem. 12 hour days looking at these 6 screens is getting to me! Thanks All! Andrew I would like to mark you answer as correct.