# Invalid object name 'NCSysem.dbo.PurchaseDetailTbl

Tags: c#, wpf

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gaop5.jpg)

Before My database name was NSSystem.bka

I renamed it to dwarozhmadxal.bak
Now when i insert data to purchasedetail table this error is show

Thanks for helping me

Comment: well obviously you have changed database name so Entity Frame work is trying to connect to your db with same old name. and can't find that db so giving you this error

Comment: You'll need to update entity models in your project if you are using DB First Approach. or manually make changes everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for replying dear , but i deleted the entity model in visual studio and creating new model with renamed db!

Comment: I don't know why it's trying to connect the old db name?

Comment: And when i find or search for (NCSystem)word Can't find any thing intire my project in visual studio

Comment: you just need to update EntityModel or EDMX if you are using EF 6. and Connect to new db `dwarozhmadxal` it will auto update where ever it is required.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947511/entity-framework-how-do-you-refresh-the-model-when-the-db-changes

Comment: I updated it more than 5 times or deleting after creating finally it's not solved