# Entity Framework - how do I update correctly?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I get the following error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMgyO.png

My system: on server startup, I load all database accounts into a list `Accounts_`.

Every 5 minutes I want to update all accounts in the database with updated `Accounts_` entries.

So I change for example the level from an entry in `Accounts_` and want to sync it to the database. Currently I get the error shown above, but second point is that that update all accounts - but I want to update all that have been changed.

My code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKb23.png

Comment: how do you invoke that method?

Comment: I have not seen this exception before.  Usual issue with Entity you made changes to the Database tables or classes in c# and then did not refresh the mapping file (EDMX).  The EDMX file are the rules the link the database tables to the c# classes.  The linking has to be correct for the code to run.  See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947511/entity-framework-how-do-you-refresh-the-model-when-the-db-changes

Comment: please post the actual code and error message as formatted text in the question, not as image. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/479251

Comment: Consider moving the SaveChangesAsync() call outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
internal static async void SaveAllAccounts()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var db = new gtaContext())
            {
                foreach (var accounts in Model.ServerAccounts.Accounts_.ToList())
                {
                    db.Entry(accounts).State = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Modified;
                    db.Accounts.Update(accounts);
                }
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{e}");
        }
    }
```

sometimes "Connection not opened"