# Does it make sense to make a mid table for the error: Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a department entity:

```cs
    public class Department : AuditableBaseEntity
    {
        public Company Company { get; set; }
        public Field Field { get; set; }
        public Employee Employee { get; set; } // Department Manager
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public Department ParentDepartment { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; } // Other employees of the department
        public virtual ICollection<DepartmentSurvey> DepartmentSurveys { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<OvertimeAttendance> OvertimeAttendances { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<WorkAttendance> WorkAttendances { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<DepartmentTask> DepartmentTasks { get; set; }
    }
```

When i try to Add-Migration this error occurs: `Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Department.Employee' of type 'Employee'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.`

Which is the best practice in my case? Creating a mid table named EmployeeJob or JobEmployee and adding a role enum in this mid table, and then defining the manager in there, then delete the
`public Employee Employee { get; set; } // Department Manager`
line

and change line

```
public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
```

to this:

```
public virtual ICollection<EmployeeJob> EmployeeJob{ get; set; }
```

or leave all as it is and configure it in somewhere else (i don't know .net core much so where to configure this) ?

Comment: There is a mapping file between your database and the c# classes.  The best way of updating the mapping is to add the tables/columns to the database and then refresh the mapping which will automatically update the classes to match the changes in the database.

Comment: @jdweng any documentation?

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947511/entity-framework-how-do-you-refresh-the-model-when-the-db-changes?force_isolation=true

Comment: Post the Employee.  You have introduced two separate relationships between Employee and Department, so you will need to configure them on both entities.