# how can i update my datagrid when any modification done in database using entity framework in wpf

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

When i bind database with my application using entity framework it show data on datagrid but when i do changes in database  externally it does not reflect in datagrid.i need a code for which synchronize the database with my datagrid.so i can reflect any modification done in database then it will automatically update the datagrid.

Comment: I am not an expert into entity-frameworks but from the problem, I think its mostly because of the cache. Check if entity-framework is caching any data previously retrieved.

Comment: Are you talking about structural changes like adding a column or a table? Or do you mean data, like adding or changing rows?

Answer (score 1):

Update you edmx file. When you modify DB you need to update your.edmx file.
Follow following link to update edmx.

[How do you update an edmx file with database changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708189/how-do-you-update-an-edmx-file-with-database-changes)