# Seeding a table with Foreign key

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I encountered a problem where I cant seed an SQL script since it has a foreign key constraint, I tried context.SaveChanges() but it isn't working. Is there any way how this can be done?

```
protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    List<Type> types = new List<Type>();
    types.Add(new Type() { Type = "Fair" });
    types.Add(new Type() { Type = "Great" });

    context.Type.AddRange(types);

    context.SaveChanges();

    var baseDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.Replace("\\bin", string.Empty) + "\\Paths";

    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(File.ReadAllText(baseDir + "\\Types.sql"));
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(File.ReadAllText(baseDir + "\\Category.sql"));

    base.Seed(context);
}
```

Model:

```
public class Type
{
   [Key]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are using Entity.  Do you have to refresh the mapping data so any changes you made to the database (or c# classes) are synchronized?

Comment: Yes exectly @jdweng

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708189/how-do-you-update-an-edmx-file-with-database-changes

Comment: Show the `Type` model

Comment: @FarhadZamani edited it

Comment: Call save changes multiple times. Seed the required tables, save, then seed the tables using the FK.

Comment: @James I'm using context.SaveChanges() but nothing is saved it's crashing on the last context.Databse because of the foreignKey constraint

Comment: Yeah, you need to call that twice. Once to seed the table with the PK, then again to seed the table using that as a FK. If you try and do it all at once the rows won't exist yet. If you look in database, if it saved the first set correctly, you'll see it in there

Comment: Show `Category` class or `Category.sql` data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question has been solved, the problem was that the data generated was not always the same, hence tweeking was made to INSERT the same data (Id) always the same

Comment: So nobody had any hope of guessing that to help you. Highlights that you need to write better questions and give more info going forward. Good you got it sorted.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Type` class has not property with `Type` name. you must change the `Type` property to `Title`

```cs
List<Type> types = new List<Type>();

types.Add(new Type() { Title = "Fair" });//NOTE THIS
types.Add(new Type() { Title = "Great" });//NOTE THIS

context.Type.AddRange(types);
context.SaveChanges();
```

then remove `base.Seed(context);`

Comment: You'd think the compiler would highlight that one.