# EF UpdateModel: how to refresh only specific entities

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-database-first

Is there a way to avoid a refresh of each entity in the entitymodel on model refresh.

For example we have a database with an order and invoice table.
Both tables are mapped to entities in the entity model.

During development we modify the order table in database with a new field.
Is there a way / tool to only refresh the order entity when refreshing the EDMX ?

We're using EF4 on .NET 4.0 with database first approach.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As answered here [Updating your edmx to reflect changes made in your db (.net linq-to-entities)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690248/updating-your-edmx-to-reflect-changes-made-in-your-db-net-linq-to-entities) :-

> Update/delete from the EDMX is not always functional. If the model
>   doesn't get updated on clicking Update Model from Database let's say
>   when you have updated a view/table in the DB, do the following:
>
> 1) Delete the view/table from the model diagram
>   2) Switch the EDMX to
>   xml view (right click the edmx file and select "Open With")
>   3) Search
>   and delete the xml entity elements
>   4) Switch back to EDMX view
>
> 5) Click Update Model from Database
>
> This should reflect any kind of change you made to the DB to your
>   EDMX. It's cumbersome, but works flawlessly.
>
> In an ideal world, i would expect the Update Model from Database to
>   sync the changes from DB to EDMX. But, it doesn't work most of the
>   time.

Comment: 1/2
So practical, what you say is that:
I add a new field to my order table in database.
Then I go to the edmx and delete the entity from the diagram.
Then I open the edmx in xml view and delete all entity elements of Order. Finnaly I update the model from database through the updatemodel wizard and select the table in the add tab.

Comment: 2/2
The problem is that at the same time my collegue has modified an other table in database, for instance he added a new field to the table invoice. When i click update model from database i also update the invoice entity. Even if i only selected to add the order table in the updatemodel wizard.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the EDMX xml manually, but you need to understand the entire structure of it