# Can't update my model from database with Update wizard ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, updatemodel

I made some changes on my db using SQL Mangamnet Studio. And everything is fine there. But when I open Visual studio, going to my model .edmx open diagram, right clik-> "Update model from database..." I got this http://postimg.org/image/4vsbg0k8d/ , but I can't select anything to update. When I click "Finish", it don't update anything.

EDIT: I added new table to database, if it means anything.

Comment: Have a look at pencilslate's answered here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690248/updating-your-edmx-to-reflect-changes-made-in-your-db-net-linq-to-entities

Comment: Delete the previous .edmx and create new one, every time when change in database ....